# NSMenuItem number bubble?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have seen something like this:

[image: rounded numberfields]

in a Menulet on the right of menu items and I can't figure out how to do it.

Can anyone elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: I have found out what it is called but no idea how to add it to a menu item... It is known as a badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this from Cocoa using the custom view behavior of the NSMenuItem.